# Selecting an item in windows form listbox by typing?

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-forms-designer

I have a listbox with country names. I´m using Windows Forms in VS2015 (C#).
While selecting a name in listBox by typing, it only allows one letter. So if I type "A" it will jump to the first item starting with "A" but if I press "As", listbox viewing the items starting with "s". 
I found this answer for combobox and textbox:
  [Selecting an item in comboBox by typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187963/selecting-an-item-in-combobox-by-typing])
but look's like listbox doesn't support AutoCompleteMode. 
Is there any solution ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562989/listbox-items-as-autocompletecustomsource-for-a-textbox

Comment: I think you woukld be much better using a combobox in DropDownStyle.Simple

Comment: See [this](https://www.codeproject.com/tips/881637/type-ahead-suggestion-box-using-listbox) for a complete tutorial on how to do that.

Comment: @CodingYoshi thanks for your help.  I solved my problem with base on that post. BTW there is a small typo, one bracket "{" is missing after this line:
 private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)

Answer (score 1):

Please, consider implementing your own searching method. ListBox doesn't support required functionallity by design. Anyway, you can prepare a method on TextChanged event for TextBox which at the time searches for results in collection.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some sample code.  Drop a TextBox above your ListBox.  Wire up the TextChanged event appropriately, and this should mimic the autocomplete behaviour of a ComboBox (for example)...

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        listBox1.Items.AddRange(new[] { "Tom", "Dick", "Harry", "Henry" });
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var textBox = (TextBox)sender;
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = textBox.TextLength == 0 ?
            -1 : listBox1.FindString(textBox.Text);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this one maybe:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a8e31841-1ba9-4990-b0e3-bdee489555af/autocomplete-textbox-on-listbox?forum=csharpgeneral

Or this one:
http://vbcity.com/blogs/xtab/archive/2012/09/22/windows-forms-combining-autocomplete-and-listbox-selection.aspx

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: If I could, I would

Answer (score 0):

You should use a ComboBox with DropDownStyle.Simple. The ListBox was never intended to have this functionality, and forcing it to do so is usually a waste of time better spent.

You may also want to consider a third party control.  Telerik, for example, has the [DropDownList](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/dropdown-listcontrol-and-checkeddropdownlist/dropdownlist/dropdownlist) which extends a ComboBox and makes it do exactly what you want to do, with options on how it does it.

Comment: thanks for advice I opted for another solution. I need multi-selection option and ComboBox doesn't have one.