# Searchable Combobox in Office Ribbon Control (Addin Express)

Tags: c#, .net, outlook, office-addins, addin-express

I'm developing an outlook addin using ***Addin Express Library***. I'm currently using the adxribboncontrol.I need to implement ability to search the control based on user input.For a normal winforms control this can be easily implemented as suggested in this SO question [Selecting an item in comboBox by typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187963/selecting-an-item-in-combobox-by-typing)

But i dont know how to implment this is office ribbon control.The control does not have the relavent properties.How can i get over this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI), nor Add-in Express, doesn't provide anything for that.  It is not possible on the ribbon. It has a limited number of controls.

Instead, I'd suggest creating a view/form region in Outlook where you can place any .net controls with the required functionality. See [Advanced Outlook view and form regions](https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/outlook-regions-basics.php) for more information.